# How to design a dependency list and store it

Tags: c#, sqlite, design-patterns

I am working on a game which as a series of quests.  There are many quests available to the user at any time, however certain quests depend on others being completed first before they are available.  You can look to WoW for possibly the best implementation of this.  As you complete various quests, then game state is updated to reflect new options available to the user.

I am curious as to how to build this efficiently.  For example:

```
Quest A: no dependency
Quest B: no dependency
Quest C: dependent on B complete
Quest D: dependent on C and A both complete
```

Essentially, this becomes a graph with node C having B as a parent, and node D having nodes C and A as parents.  As we complete the Quests, the app will look to the children having all completed parents as the ones being available to the user.

I'm sure this is a common problem.  I can understand it theoretically, however I'm struggling with the implementation of it.

I am working in C# / sqlite.  I want to store the Quest data in my db.  I as thinking of a table called Quest (not the tribe) for the quest details, but I am struggling with the best implementation for the dependency information.  Particularly, building it in such a way that is easy to maintain.

Any ideas?

Comment: you said yourself building a graph for the quests IDs, you can Topological sort it to know the next quest for the user. usually you'd store a graph in Adjacency lists. save in the db the current quest ID

Comment: I guess that's where I'm struggling.  What's the best way to implement the Adjacency list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can setup the dependencies in code because they are not changed that often, if at all. To achieve what you want, you need to create `Quest` class with a collection of dependent quests.

```
public class Quest
{
    private List<Quest> quests = new List<Quest>();

    // you need a validation in setter.
    public bool Complete { get; set; }

    public bool CanStart()
    {
        return quests.All(o => o.Complete);
    }

    public void Add(Quest quest)
    {
        this.quests.Add(quest);
    }

    public void Remove(Quest quest)
    {
        this.quests.Remove(quest);
    }
}
```

You can configure `Quest` dependency by adding dependent `Quest` to the collection. For example, to setup 4 quests with dependencies like what you want in the question would be something like below.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SetupABCDQuestTest()
{
    var questA = new Quest();
    Assert.IsTrue(questA.CanStart());

    var questB = new Quest();
    Assert.IsTrue(questB.CanStart());

    var questC = new Quest();
    questC.Add(questB);
    Assert.IsFalse(questC.CanStart());

    questB.Complete = true;
    Assert.IsTrue(questC.CanStart());

    var questD = new Quest();
    questD.Add(questA);
    questD.Add(questC);
    Assert.IsFalse(questD.CanStart());

    questA.Complete = true;
    questC.Complete = true;

    Assert.IsTrue(questD.CanStart());
}
```

With [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), you can setup dependency the way you want, as complex or as simple as you want!

Comment: I always have such a strong DB bias for data like this, but this will be much easier to work with, at least to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is a many-to-many relationship, so the obvious solution is a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Quest (
    ID,
    [...]
);
CREATE TABLE QuestDependency (
    Child  REFERENCES Quest(ID),
    Parent REFERENCES Quest(ID)
);
```